# How I can to make collision in table by row not by cells?

Tags: html, html-table

I want to avoid the resize of `<table>` when I write in a cell a long string.

**This is the code [from w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_cellpadding):**

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill </td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p>Try to change the padding to 5px.</p>
```

but if I write this:

```
<tr>
    <td>Jill jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
</tr>
```

then the cell which contains "Jill jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj" expand and merge the next cell.

**What I want is:** to do expand and merge by rows not by cell (i.e: when the cell need to expand it must to stop in border of the next cell and take rows to complete the string).

**The expected output is:**
[image: here what I want]

Comment: You want this to be done dynamically or could you manually do it with a rowspan attribute?

Comment: I try rowspan attribute it did not work :(

Comment: you need to give your td a width and add a word-break properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `table-layout:fixed` to your `<table>` and setting the `word-wrap` property for your cells (`<td>`). Additionally to make sure the content of the cells stay at top you have to add `vertical-align:top` to your cells too!

**See the following solution:**

```css
table {
  table-layout:fixed;
  width:100%;
}
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  padding: 5px;
}
td {
  vertical-align:top;
  word-wrap:break-word; 
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>JillJillJillJillJillJillJillJillJillJillJillJillJillJillJillJillJillJill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you verey much @Sebastian Brosch